# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '28/04/2022 10:51'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, time

While reading a csv file I get this error

```
  File "C:\Users\cast.py", line 1181, in astype_nansafe
    return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '28/04/2022 10:51'
```

I was thinking of changing the csv data in excel but that will take time any simpler solution?

```
 DATA_TYPES = {
        "cycle_index": "int32",
        "step_index": "int32",
        "step_time": "float32",
        "test_time": "float64",
        "current": "float32",
        "voltage": "float32",
        "charge_capacity": "float64",
        "discharge_capacity": "float64",
        "charge_energy": "float64",
        "discharge_energy": "float64",
        "date_time_iso":"float32",
    }
```

The library wants my csv data types to be in this format to work

The link to the library:
https://tri-amdd.github.io/beep/Python%20tutorials/advanced_structuring/#2-metadata-dictionary

Comment: Yeah, maybe `28/04/2022 10:51` istn't exactly a float, but more a datetime. Perhaps you just want to read it as a string for he time being and later convert the data into whatever you want.

Comment: yes but the library I am using needs it to be in float to work.

Comment: But what float? seconds, millis, nanoseconds? Please be more clear in what the expected result should be.

Comment: That's great, and what float value do you expect from `28/04/2022 10:51`? Milliseconds since 1970?

Comment: I have edited the question. I myself am confused with this library it wants me to convert the date_time_iso to float32. May be dumb to ask but I am also confused.

Comment: Does the library you are using have any documentation?

Comment: Yes I can share a link if you want

Comment: Docs: `date_time_iso: Date time in UTC time zone, formatted using .isoformat()` so parse the string as datetime, then call isoformat().

Comment: `.isoformat()` returns a string, but those docs also suggest they want float32 (which doesn't even exist in native Python!). The code example they give also seems kind of convoluted to me (why use pytz to set UTC? datetime.timezone can do that! Why use an `apply` to convert? pandas has pd.to_datetime!).